# Assign distinct y coordinate to each categorical value

Tags: d3.js, row, scale, categorical-data

I have a clear requirement to calculate a y coordinate in a d3 context, but I am struggling to...

**a)** find the d3 (scaling?) component and usage pattern to deliver the solution

**b)** identify any navigable d3 API resources which would help me find *a)*

I have a list of events which have a start and finish time and which are each associated with a process in which they execute sequentially. It's natural to present this like a multi-track interface (a bit like an audio editor or a gantt chart) in which each process/track is allocated its own horizontal swim lane, and the events are laid out horizontally according to their start and end time. It might end up looking a bit like this [view from a research publication](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Gantt-chart-for-a-best-schedule-generated-by-sequence-1-2-and-3_fig6_271740414)

[image]

Event data items have a reference to their process id (in the diagram shown the process ids would be M1, M2 and the events would be the little boxes labelled with numbers). I know each event's start and end time (determining their x coordinate and width) but I need to put the rectangle for the action in the right process row (y coordinate).

The list of events will be updating continually as they start and finish, and possibly mediated by a filter/brush in the future.

The number of rows varies as the number of processes varies. For this reason, only after joining a list of events (and encountering all the process ids they refer to) do you know how many rows are needed, the row height, and therefore what each event's y scale position should be. When a new event item enters the selection which points to a new process id, the scale should rejig to add an extra row. When it exits the selection, it may have been the last one in that process row, so then the row should disappear.

Is there a pattern for assigning the y coordinate of an event's row on a dynamic basis by its (categorical) process id for a dynamic list of event data?

How do I find patterns and solutions for a case like this?

Comment: Can you post a picture / sketch of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I posted a graphic which may help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet using the following data model:

```
[
  {
    label: string; // Row label
    color: string; // Row color
    items: [ { label: string; start: number; end: number; }, ...];
  },
  ...
]
```

The snippet uses `d3.scaleLinear` and `d3.axisBottom` routines.

**NOTE**: I use `_top` because (for some misterious reason) `top` is already used... I suppose it's a bug in D3 **V5** and suggest to use **V6**.

```js
const data = [
  {
    label: 'M1',
    color: 'red',
    items: [
      {label: 'A', start: 10, end: 12},
      {label: 'B', start: 15, end: 20}
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'M2',
    color: 'orange',
    items: [
      {label: 'C', start: 0, end: 4},
      {label: 'D', start: 4, end: 6},
      {label: 'E', start: 11, end: 17}
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'M3',
    color: 'yellow',
    items: [
      {label: 'F', start: 0, end: 3},
      {label: 'G', start: 3, end: 9},
      {label: 'H', start: 9, end: 14}
    ]
  }
];


const ticks = 25;
const left = 50;
const _top = 50;
const rowHeight = 20;
const labelWidth = 30;
const bottom = _top + data.length * rowHeight;

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, ticks])
  .range([0, 300]);
  
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

svg.append("g")
    .attr('transform', `translate(${left}, ${bottom - 1})`)
  .call(xAxis);
      
let i, j;      
for (i = 0; i <= ticks; i++)
    svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', xScale(i) + left)
    .attr('x2', xScale(i) + left)
    .attr('y1', _top)
    .attr('y2', bottom)
    .style('stroke', 'black');
    
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', left)
    .attr('x2', xScale(ticks) + left)
    .attr('y1', _top + i * rowHeight)
    .attr('y2', _top + i * rowHeight)
    .style('stroke', 'black');
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', left - labelWidth)
    .attr('y', _top + i * rowHeight)
    .attr('width', labelWidth)
    .attr('height', rowHeight)
    .style('fill', data[i].color)
    .style('stroke', 'black')
  svg.append('text')
    .text(data[i].label)
    .attr('x', left - labelWidth / 2)
    .attr('y', _top + (i + 0.5) * rowHeight)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .style('fill', 'black');
    
  const items = data[i].items;  
  for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    const x = left + xScale(items[j].start);
    const width = xScale(items[j].end) - xScale(items[j].start);
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', x)
    .attr('y', _top + i * rowHeight)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', rowHeight)
    .style('fill', data[i].color)
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    
  svg.append('text')
    .text(items[j].label)
    .attr('x', x + width / 2)
    .attr('y', _top + (i + 0.5) * rowHeight)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .style('fill', 'black');
    
  }  
}
```

```css
text {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="200">
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of work, Michael! Thanks with your patience with my poorly-worded question. Just starting out with D3. Haven't established a good mental model or tools for drafting half-complete problem cases yet. Can already calculate all the coordinate structures that in Typescript+React. Using D3 primitives seems to be about allowing the data to drive the numbers, using helpful primitives driven by selections. I would like to know what D3 primitive exists to NOT hard-code the row height - the total graphic height is known, but the number of rows is not known until the data is there.

Comment: A related question is how to exploit D3 to dynamically project the event data into a sufficiently row-oriented form as it isn't row oriented to begin with. A better question-asker would have provided example data. I'm going to go back and re-shape the question properly based on your excellent example. Would you advise not to bother learning D3 and just to use Javascript/Typescript to make calculations and then draw the SVG explicitly?

Comment: I think I'll mark your answer as the best response to my poorly written question and write one with a proper reference D3 implementation following your example.

Comment: Inspired by the clarity of your answer I made an attempt to construct a clearer reference example and focus the question on my scales which should be driven by data joins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463228/what-primitives-will-help-my-d3-scales-update-dynamically-according-to-my-joined