# Get d3 scales to update dynamically according to joined data?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, scale, categorical-data, gantt-chart

In the code example below (visible in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-meadow-g13ch?file=/src/App.tsx:51-533)) I am rendering the original event data more or less as I wish, but recalculating all coordinates and scales for every change.

The aim of this visualisation is to show events which take place over time (with a start and finish) in multiple concurrent processes, where each process has its own horizontal 'swim lane'.

However I want to use d3 scale primitives properly. Currently I am running an explicit reduce over all my data in every render cycle.

By building my own reduce operations I think I'm not really using D3 properly. The case of adding a single new event which doesn't cause a re-scale should be performant. Given the way I'm using D3 it feels like I may as well just render the graphics using React to create SVGs - I'm effectively recalculating everything every time anyway, so I'm not taking advantage of the enter, exit logic of a d3 selection.

However I don't know how to 'wire' extent, row-calculation and time scale operations to the data selection. For this reason I am making these calculations outside and re-rendering everything every time.

[image]

Y-AXIS: In my code you can see a calculation for rowHeight and a lookup table for the (categorical data) `event.process`. I am sure there must be a proper d3 pattern for this that lazy-updates these only considering ***entered*** data. I'm expecting Some kind of categorical scale allocating unique names to unique rows on the y axis. Can I use scaleBand? If so, how do I bind it to my data. I would expect the primitive to allocate new categories (needing their own row-spacing) and retire unused categories (which no longer need their own row-spacing) on the fly. Is there a way to update the y axis numbers according to the list of events in the data?

X-AXIS: I am also having to calculate the x-coordinate bounds of the time domain (to find the earliest `event.start` and the latest `event.stop`) explicitly before creating scales. I am having to calculate time offset from the earliest start explicitly. Since this is also determined by the event data I expect the bounds-detection, diffing and scaling could be achieved by some d3 primitive but I don't know what. I'm looking at d3 'extent' but how do I ensure the extent is updated when the data changes, except by just running everything from scratch again.

The data looks [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-meadow-g13ch?file=/src/App.tsx:51-533)...

```
let events: Event[] = [
  {
    start: 0,
    stop: 3,
    process: "root"
  },
  {
    start: 1,
    stop: 5,
    process: "child2"
  },
  {
    start: 3,
    stop: 5,
    process: "root"
  },
  {
    start: 3,
    stop: 7,
    process: "child1"
  },
  {
    start: 5,
    stop: 6,
    process: "child2"
  },
  {
    start: 7,
    stop: 8,
    process: "root"
  },
  {
    start: 8,
    stop: 9,
    process: "root"
  },
  {
    start: 8,
    stop: 9,
    process: "child1"
  }
];
```

My existing (inefficient) scaling and projection code which just re-runs everything each time looks [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-meadow-g13ch?file=/src/MultiTrack.tsx:804-2254)...

```
      if (events.length > 0) {
        const svgWidth = 300;
        const svgHeight = 150;

        const firstStart = events.reduce(
          (min, event) => Math.min(event.start, min),
          Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
        );
        const lastStop = events.reduce(
          (max, event) => Math.max(event.stop, max),
          Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
        );
        const duration = lastStop - firstStart;

        const countByProcess = events.reduce<Record<string, number>>(
          (countMap, event) => {
            countMap[event.process] = countMap[event.process] + 1 || 1;
            return countMap;
          },
          {}
        );

        if (duration > 0) {
          const xScale = scaleLinear()
            .domain([firstStart, lastStop])
            .range([0, svgWidth]);

          const color = scaleOrdinal(schemeCategory10);

          const rowHeight = svgHeight / Object.keys(countByProcess).length;

          selection
            .data(events)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", (e) => xScale(e.start - firstStart))
            .attr("width", (e) => xScale(e.stop - e.start))
            .attr(
              "y",
              (e) => Object.keys(countByProcess).indexOf(e.process) * rowHeight
            )
            .attr("height", rowHeight)
            .attr("fill", (_, i) => color(i.toString()));
          return;
        }
      }
      selection.data([]);
```

Comment: I suppose you want to render events with D3 `enter / exit` pattern and use scales for both X and Y or just for X?

Comment: I think I get your question about dynamic update for the scales. If you change the number of rows, or the frame range, but the chart width and height remain the same, you can change scaling factor: `xScale.domain([newStart, newStop])`, and then re-render your chart

Comment: Right, but for the x axis I'm having to CALCULATE newStart, newStop myself rather than using d3 primitives. I'm looking at d3.extent now as a potential primitive for this, although how to trigger re-calculation of the scale when a new item enters the data remains a mystery. On the yAxis I don't have any candidate approach to eliminate the countByProcess 'reduction'. It is just about counting the number of distinct process ids from the data stream, allocating each of them a number from the yAxis. Again, d3 should be doing this for me I believe since it's dictated by the data. Don't know how.

Comment: Yes, I would assume this means using scales for both X and Y, and have them wired in a way which auto-updates both previously-rendered data and for newly-entering data.

Comment: You talk about "events"... So it's probably an array that only grows when a new event arrives. I don't think you need to rescale in this case. You need to change both domain and range with every new event and scroll to the right. Let me know if I understand the situation correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right apart from the scroll. I don't anticipate old events going out of view, at least for initial versions - there may be filters/brushes to do this in the long run, and yes when this is the case I will really need scales to dynamically update to reflect the current list of viewed events (e.g. when a too-old event exits from my data then the new x=0 should be the start time of the oldest event that remains within the data).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232169/discussion-between-michael-rovinsky-and-cefn).